# Eloquent Filter by relationship (ONLY last record)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship, has-many

I edit my question to be more explicative

I need to build a scope for filtering a hasMany relationship. The problem is, I want to apply that query to **last** item **ONLY**, I mean, I want my Model filtered by a column of an specific record of a HasMany relationship, is it possible?

Context: An App that have Posts, each Posts have many Statuses to keep an historic. I want to filter the Posts by the **last Status** of each one.

Posts:

```
{
    public function statuses() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Status::class); // Only last one is important for querying
    }
}
```

Then, in an scope, I would like to do something like this:

```
public function scopeIsActive(Builder $builder)
{
    return $builder->whereHas('statuses', function(Builder $q) {
        // How to apply this ONLY to last created record???
        return $q->whereDate('activation', '<=', today());
    });
}
```

And that's all!

**Edit: (Solved query)**

After some digging I solved my problem with this:

```
public function scopeIsActive(Builder $builder)
{
    return $builder->whereHas('statuses', function (Builder $q) {
        return $q->whereDate('activation', '<=', today()) // applies to all
            ->where('statuses.id', function ($sub) { // applies to specific one
            return $sub->select('id')
                ->from('statuses')
                ->whereColumn('post_id', 'statuses.id')
                ->latest()
                ->limit(1);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
public function others() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Other::class); // Only last one is important for querying
}
```

you can just do :

```php
public function other() 
{
    return $this->hasOne(Other::class)->latest();
}
```

and then

```php
public function scopeCurrentActive(Builder $builder)
{
    return $builder->whereHas('other', function(Builder $q) {
        return $q->whereDate('activation', '<=', today());
    });
}
```

But You can't make a custom order, If you want to make a custom order, oyou have to use subqueries :

```php
return Model::orderByDesc(
    Other::select('arrived_at')
        ->whereColumn('model_id', 'model.id')
        ->orderBy('activation', 'desc')
        ->limit(1)
)->get();
```

If you want to learn more about subqueries, you can refer to :

https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-subquery-enhancements

For using only the last record, you might have to use a having statement like this, but I'm not sure about the exact synthax ^^

```php
public function scopeIsActive(Builder $builder)
{
    return $builder->whereHas('statuses', function (Builder $q) {
        return $q->havingRaw(Other::select('arrived_at')
        ->whereColumn('model_id', 'model.id')
        ->orderBy('activation', 'desc')
        ->limit(1)->select('activation')->toSql(), '<=' , today());
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I thougth it could work but I realized that not, the `HasOne()` relation produces the exact sql  as `HasMany()` does... So, it wont let filtering by LAST record, it will consider all related records instead of only the LAST one :(

Comment: I updated my question. Im not able to filter by last record T_T It looks like `limit(1)` is not taking effect. Im not sure if the produced SQL statement is correct or what

Comment: it's because the limit is "apply" after the query, I think you should use a having() statement, I will update my answer, but I'm not sure of the exact synthax ^^

Comment: Yes! problem was in query placement! I could solve this and edited my question. I have not tested your solution yet but probably it will works too. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

to filter by items that has activate today write:

```
public function scopeCurrentActive()
{
    return $this->whereHas('other', function($q) {
        return $q->whereDate('activation', '==', Carbon::now()->toDateString());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly meant with the *last record of each one*.

Here is how you can get all the posts that have the same status as the latest post:

```php
public function scopeIsActive(Builder $builder)
{
    $lastPostStatus = Post::select('status')
        ->orderBy('activation', 'desc')
        ->first()
        ->status;

    return $builder->where('status', $lastPostStatus);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but no, thats not what I want. I need 'All Posts that its Latest Status satisfies a condition'. I need to filter all Posts by an atribute of a hasMany relation, but only the last child of the hasMany