# Defining local Scope based on latest relation object

Tags: laravel

I have a Ticket model and a Reply model.

Every ticket hasMany Replies and each Reply belongsTo one Ticket.
I want to define a local scope on the Ticket model and run some conditions on the last reply to that Ticket.
for example, If the latest reply Is sent by me, i want to filter out that ticket from the query.

but I'm having a hard time getting the last reply to the ticket on the scope.

for example, I've tried the following:

```
    public function lastVisibleReply()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Reply::class, 'ticket_id', 'id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('is_hidden', 0)->latest()->limit(1);
    }
    public function scopeSomeConditionsOnLastReply($query)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('lastVisibleReply', function ($q){
            //some conditions
        })
   }
```

but the whereHas('lastVisibleReply') just goes over every Reply of the ticket.

when I logged the $query->toSql(), the following was the result:

```
select * 
from "replies" 
where "tickets"."id" = "replies"."ticket_id" 
// and conditions
and "replies"."deleted_at" is null
```

as you can see in the log, the "->orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('is_hidden', 0)->latest()->limit(1)" part of the relation definition, was not applied on the whereHas query.

is there a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101144/eloquent-filter-by-relationship-only-last-record

Comment: I think your description of the problem is a little hard to understand. I'm assuming the problem is, it is not checking the latest reply it is checking the latest reply that satisfies the criteria in lastVisibleReply (that teoretically can be the 3. latest sent reply)?

Comment: @mrhn
 I want to retrieve the tickets which their last reply meets certain conditions.